# Azure MSAL node ClientAuthError

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am trying to use @azure/msal-node on a node backend server.

I follow the tutorial on their Github page and when I try to call acquireTokenByCode i get this error:

```
[Tue, 30 Aug 2022 08:23:34 GMT] : @azure/msal-node@1.12.1 : Info - getAuthCodeUrl called
[Tue, 30 Aug 2022 08:23:34 GMT] : @azure/msal-node@1.12.1 : Verbose - initializeRequestScopes called
[Tue, 30 Aug 2022 08:23:34 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.12.1 : Verbose - buildOauthClientConfiguration called
[Tue, 30 Aug 2022 08:23:34 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.12.1 : Verbose - building oauth client configuration with the authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/
[Tue, 30 Aug 2022 08:23:34 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.12.1 : Verbose - createAuthority called
[Tue, 30 Aug 2022 08:23:34 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.12.1 : Verbose - Auth code client created
[Tue, 30 Aug 2022 08:23:35 GMT] : @azure/msal-node@1.12.1 : Info - acquireTokenByCode called
[Tue, 30 Aug 2022 08:23:35 GMT] : @azure/msal-node@1.12.1 : Verbose - initializeRequestScopes called
[Tue, 30 Aug 2022 08:23:35 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.12.1 : Verbose - buildOauthClientConfiguration called
[Tue, 30 Aug 2022 08:23:35 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.12.1 : Verbose - building oauth client configuration with the authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/
[Tue, 30 Aug 2022 08:23:35 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.12.1 : Verbose - createAuthority called
[Tue, 30 Aug 2022 08:23:35 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.12.1 : Verbose - Auth code client created
[Tue, 30 Aug 2022 08:23:35 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-common@7.3.0 : Info - in acquireToken call
ClientAuthError: network_error: Network request failed. Please check network trace to determine root cause. | Fetch client threw: Error: HTTP status code 401 | Attempted to reach: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
    at ClientAuthError.AuthError [as constructor] (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\@azure\msal-common\dist\index.cjs.js:500:24)
    at new ClientAuthError (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\@azure\msal-common\dist\index.cjs.js:802:28)
    at Function.ClientAuthError.createNetworkError (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\@azure\msal-common\dist\index.cjs.js:845:16)
    at NetworkManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\@azure\msal-common\dist\index.cjs.js:3418:51)
    at step (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\@azure\msal-common\dist\index.cjs.js:79:23)
    at Object.throw (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\@azure\msal-common\dist\index.cjs.js:60:53)
    at rejected (C:\Users\user\project\node_modules\@azure\msal-common\dist\index.cjs.js:51:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5) {
  errorCode: 'network_error',
  errorMessage: 'Network request failed. Please check network trace to determine root cause. | Fetch client threw: Error: HTTP status code 401 | Attempted to reach: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
  subError: '',
  name: 'ClientAuthError'
}
```

My code:

```js
const loggerOptions = {
  loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
    console.log(message);
  },
  piiLoggingEnabled: false,
  logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
}
const clientConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: loggerOptions
  }
};
publicMicrosoftClient = new msal.PublicClientApplication(clientConfig);

app.get('/connect', function (req, res) {
  const authCodeUrlParameters = {
    scopes: ['https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All', 'https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send', 'offline_access', 'openid', 'profile', 'Mail.ReadWrite', 'Mail.Send', 'MailboxSettings.Read', 'MailboxSettings.ReadWrite', 'IMAP.AccessAsUser.All'],
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:4220/redirect",
  };
  client.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters).then((response) => {
    res.json(response);
  }).catch((error) => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
});

app.get('/redirect', function (req, res) {
  const tokenRequest = {
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:4220/redirect",
    scopes: ['https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All', 'https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send', 'offline_access', 'openid', 'profile', 'Mail.ReadWrite', 'Mail.Send', 'MailboxSettings.Read', 'MailboxSettings.ReadWrite', 'IMAP.AccessAsUser.All'],
    code: req.query.code
  };
  const authCodeResponse = { code: req.query.code }
  client.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest, authCodeResponse).then((response) => {
    console.log("Successfully acquired token using Authorization Code.");
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

The first request works fine. I can connect with the link and I am well redirected on /redirect

If anyone has an idea what's going on?

Node version: 12.14.0

@azure/msal-node version: 1.12.1

Answer (score 0):

Please check ,it can be issue when DNS is not resolved  .Try to replace localhost with the IP address of your machine.

[image]

1. For native and mobile apps, use one of the following: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient` for apps using embedded browsers or with `http://localhost` for apps using system browsers.
2. As you have given `openid` `offline_access`, `profile` permissions, please check the same api permissions are given in azure ad portal and been ***`granted admin consent`*** from portal or while authentication.
3. In  authorization code flow , the client initially directs the user to the `/authorize` endpoint and requests scopes like the `openid`, `offline_access`, and `https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read` permissions from the user.

[image]

**Reference**: [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code)